# Why dropdownlist is getting assigned with wrong value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, dropdown

I am assingning a value returned from `DataTable` to a `dropdownlist` but it picks the very first value only `-1`. Why?

```
ddlBPS.SelectedValue = r["ServiceInfoInitialBPS"].ToString();
```

The value of `ServiceInfoInitialBPS` inside the datatable and db is 6.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBPS" runat="server" CssClass="form-control white">
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="01" Text="01"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="02" Text="02"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="03" Text="03"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="04" Text="04"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="05" Text="05"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="06" Text="06"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="07" Text="07"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="08" Text="08"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="09" Text="09"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="10"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="11"></asp:ListItem>

                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="12"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="13" Text="13"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="14" Text="14"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="15" Text="15"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="16" Text="16"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="17" Text="17"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="18" Text="18"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="19" Text="19"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="20" Text="20"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="21" Text="21"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Value="22" Text="22"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Why is that? I have debugged but the value assigned to it is always `-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append `"0"` before the value coming from `database`. It is a `string` value not an `int` so it should completely with `value` of option.

```
ddlBPS.SelectedValue = "0" + r["ServiceInfoInitialBPS"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the value `6` is not found because you use leading zeros as in `06`. If it's a postback you would get an exception, but since it's the initial load nothing(so the first)  item gets "selected".

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: The selected value is not in the list of available values and view
>   state or other state has been loaded (a postback has been performed).
>   For more information, see the Remarks section.

One way, fill it with a leading zero:

```
ddlBPS.SelectedValue = r["ServiceInfoInitialBPS"].ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

or (presuming it's an `int`):

```
ddlBPS.SelectedValue = r.Field<int>("ServiceInfoInitialBPS").ToString("D2");
```

Comment: Great. Thanks sir. Wish I could accept  2 answers but saw that one first